# powershell limit on Invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: powershell

I have this bit of the code:

```
$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages" 
$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

$messageQuery = "" + $url + "?`$select=Id&`$filter=HasAttachments eq true and DateTimeReceived ge " + $date
$messages = Invoke-RestMethod $messageQuery -Credential $cred 

foreach ($message in $messages.value) 
{
```

I try to download 11 attachments from 11 different emails… but I only get 10… is there a limit in the Invoke-RestMethod ? is the only reason I can find, because it works perfect up to 10 attachments…

Comment: It could be that the eleventh message is too big (`Invoke-RestMethod` uses `ConvertFrom-Json` which is limited in byte size). Although, in that case I'd expect `$messages` to be a string (and `$message.values` to fail at all)... What message count you get if you set querystring to `?\`$select=Id&\`$top=50` in the `$messageQuery` variable?

Answer (score 2):

The response from `https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages` is *paged*.

The default number of items per page is 10.

The maximum you can request is 50.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#page-results

The most important part when it comes to paging it to inspect the response body for an `"@odata.nextLink"`, e.g.

```
"@odata.nextLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/?%24top=10&%24skip=10"
```

If that is present; follow that link to the next page of results!

Comment: I do get your point, but I implemented the top=999 in the code, as Avshalom suggested and I still got 10 results...

Comment: Then it sounds like you're misusing/misinterpreting the purpose of `top` in this API call. I suggest you follow the `nextLink` and have a look at the subsequent values of `nextLink` and see what actually changes. Better yet - go find the API documentation and give that a read!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#page-results

Comment: how can I explore it?

I tried 

$messages2 = Invoke-RestMethod $messages.odata.nextLink -Credential $cred
$messages2 = Invoke-RestMethod $messages.@odata.nextLink -Credential $cred
$messages2 = Invoke-RestMethod @odata.nextLink -Credential $cred

all of them return nothing...

Comment: Rather than running an `Invoke-RestMethod` call - just `Write-Host` the values of the various `$messages.odata...` to see if any return a value. If they're all empty then run a `$messages | Get-Member` to see what properties _are_ available.

Comment: Did anyone notice @Chicago1988 uses `$top=999` as he comments. It is limited to 50 as @gvee says.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `$top` parameter to your QueryString (if no other params):

```
$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?\`$top=50"
```

or:

```
$messageQuery = "" + $url + "?`$select=Id&`$filter=HasAttachments eq true and DateTimeReceived ge " + $date + '&top=50'
```

Comment: It still downloads only 10... the resulting url is: https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?$select=Id&$filter=HasAttachments eq true and DateTimeReceived ge 2018-02-28&top=999  is it correct?